# HornetQ implementation on Wildfly 9

Tags: java, jboss, jms, wildfly, wildfly-9

I am migrating my jboss from 4.0.5 to Wildfly9,

Technology : 
Wildfly 9
My application is deployed on localhost

But when I try to create connection using following code,

```
import java.util.Map;

import org.hornetq.api.core.TransportConfiguration;
import org.hornetq.api.jms.HornetQJMSClient;
import org.hornetq.api.jms.JMSFactoryType;
import org.hornetq.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnectorFactory;
import org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQConnectionFactory;


Map<String, Object> connectionParams = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        connectionParams.put("port", "5445");
        connectionParams.put("host", "localhost");

        TransportConfiguration transportConfiguration = new TransportConfiguration(NettyConnectorFactory.class.getName(), connectionParams);
        //
        HornetQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = HornetQJMSClient.createConnectionFactoryWithoutHA(JMSFactoryType.CF, transportConfiguration);
        try {
            connectionFactory.createConnection();
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I am getting following exceptions.

```
javax.jms.JMSException: Failed to create session factory
    at org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQConnectionFactory.createConnectionInternal(HornetQConnectionFactory.java:673)
    at org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQConnectionFactory.createConnection(HornetQConnectionFactory.java:112)
    at org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQConnectionFactory.createConnection(HornetQConnectionFactory.java:107)
    at Demo.main(Demo.java:176)
Caused by: HornetQNotConnectedException[errorType=NOT_CONNECTED message=HQ119007: Cannot connect to server(s). Tried with all available servers.]
    at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.createSessionFactory(ServerLocatorImpl.java:905)
    at org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQConnectionFactory.createConnectionInternal(HornetQConnectionFactory.java:669)
    ... 3 more
```

I am not sure Why this is happening

I also read the [document](http://hornetq.blogspot.in/2009/10/understanding-connectors-acceptors.html)

Let me know if anyone face this issue earlier.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Port 5445 is open in your computer?

Comment: Yes as follow  
TCP    172.26.121.246:61375   172.26.121.246:5445    TIME_WAIT  
TCP    172.26.121.246:61376   172.26.121.246:5445    TIME_WAIT

Comment: Try to replace  `connectionParams.put("host", "localhost");` to `connectionParams.put("host", "172.26.121.246");`

Comment: Yes now it is working, but i don't understand why it is like this, because I am running my application on localhost, so i thought localhost , my all IPs should be able to work.

Comment: Please read this https://developer.jboss.org/thread/168789?tstart=0&_sscc=t You listen only one interface.